# How to connect to MySQL in JSP page: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I am trying to connect JSP to a database without performing any DDL or DML commands.

Here's my JSP:

```jsp
 <%@ page import="java.sql.*" %> 
 <%@ page import="java.io.*" %> 
 <html> <head> <title>Connection with mysql database</title>
 </head> 
 <body>
 <h1>Connection status</h1>
 <% 
 try {
 String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bharath"; 
 Connection connection = null; 
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); 
 connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "root");
 if(!connection.isClosed())
 %>
 <font size="+3" color="green"></b>
 <% 
 out.println("Successfully connected to " + "MySQL server using TCP/IP...");
 connection.close();
 }
 catch(Exception ex){
 %></font>
 <font size="+3" color="red"></b>
 <%
 out.println("Unable to connect to database.");
 } 
 %>
 </font></body> </html>
```

The exception in the catch block gets executed. So what might have gone wrong in the try block. I installed MySql with default settings with user as `"root"` and database name as `"bharath"`.

```
 Exception - 
 java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4096) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4028) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:919) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1694) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1244) at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2412) at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2445) at
```

Comment: Could you try printing exception stacktrace.

Comment: Yes i even tried that. But it doesn't prints the exception. It only shows the one mentioned in header tag i.e., "Connection Status"

Comment: I mean, just put `ex.printStackTrace(out);` in the `catch` block, and share the result please.

Comment: Ok. I tried as u said. Replaced out.println line with ex.printStackTrace(out);....There is an HTTP Status 500 error explaining "org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:"

Comment: Your exception handling is bad. You should log or throw the exception, not ignore it and print a nothing-saying sentence. The exception basically contains the whole answer to your problem.

Comment: By the way, your JSP contains bad practices and your HTML contains deprecated elements. Are you absolutely positive that you're reading up to date resources while learning JSP and HTML? It seems that you're reading a 90's book/tutorial on the subject instead of a more recent one.

Comment: @BalusC I agree with you. But, Being a beginner for JSPs im just trying to learn with simple concepts and then go for the higher standards.

Comment: @PeterRader No Im using NetBeans IDE

Comment: Didn't you satisfied with the answers here? Please accept answers.

Comment: Anyone reasonable to tell him not to do that in `JSP`?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
out.println("Unable to connect to database.");
```

you should write

```
ex.printStackTrace(new java.io.PrintWriter(out));
```

Will point you to the main problem.

Comment: I get a "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" when i replace as u said. Here's my classpath "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar;". Should i change the classpath?

Comment: hm, looks good. can you post the full stacktrace into the question, as well as the first 10 lines of tomcat's logging?

Comment: Should i paste the exception? And what is tomcat logging? Can u explain plzz.

Comment: The stacktrace is the type of the exception, the message from the exception and the class/method:linenumber-combinaten starts with "at ". The stacktrace usually spans 4-30 lines of hard-to-read code.

The actual logging is all information from your log-files located in "C:\Programm files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\logs\". 1. Delete those logfiles. 2. Start the server and reproduce the problem. 3. post the first lines of the catalina-file located in "C:\Programm files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\logs\". Sorry i have no characters left on the comment here!

Comment: Not enougth informations. Post the 10 Lines to the question. Post the Stacktrace to the problem too.

Comment: By the way. Can u please tell me why did you ask for log file? Whats the use of that?

Comment: the first 10 line a general overview about all neccessary things tomcat works with, such as jdk, os, pathnames, classpath and so on. see, if anyone has a similar problem he is able to compare his expiriences with you.

Answer (score 0):

There's no required `newInstance()` of the driver. It should be just loaded.

Put the `mysql-connector-java-x.x.x-bin.jar` to the `WEB-INF\lib`. The credentials you supply in your connection should be working. If it's not working or you got wrong database name in the connection url or you got wrong port or you got wrong host.

There's also a better opportunity to get connection from a pool. Look at [Connection Pooling](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-j2ee-concepts-connection-pooling.html).

Comment: @sribharath have you included the driver on the classpath?

Comment: You're not answering the concrete problem at all. Whatever you're suggesting are merely style/design issues, not technical/functional issues. This should have been posted as a comment, not as an answer. Whoever upvoted this non-answer has to reconsider his upvote.

Comment: @BalusC I'm trying to answer the question here not to solve problem or this if FAQ issue?

Comment: Removing `newInstance()` doesn't solve any problem as described by the OP. Using a connection pool doesn't solve any problem as described by the OP. So, you are simply not answering his concrete question at all. You're merely mentioning some best practices and buzz words instead of really solving his concrete problem.

Comment: No, that's just a fact. Or do you have arguments which proves otherwise?

Comment: @RomanC Here's my classpath - "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar;"

Comment: @sribharath This is nice that you have the driver but Tomcat is loading your webapp in it's own classloader. So, you need to place the driver to the dir where it able to find it. I used webroot/WEB-INF/lib but you can place it to $CATALINA_HOME/lib

Comment: @sribharath It's the first dir in your last comment.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have the jar for "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" added in the classpath.

Comment: "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar;" is my classpath. Should anything be added or changed?

Comment: this is correct, can you try copying the jar "mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar" to WEB-INF/lib folder

Comment: Do you mean WEB-INF in Tomcat Server? Should i create a lib folder in it?

Comment: you must have created a web application for this jsp page, see directory structure here http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/P.Rounce/myhtml/elecTran_technical_manual/c1452.html lib folder can be added inside WEB-INF folder in the web application.

Comment: Yes. I have done the way u said. But the "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" is displayed again

Comment: if you are using eclipse, select the jar from the "Project Explorer" window, do a right click, select "Build Path -> Add to Build Path"